# How can I shorten this repetitive C# TextBox.Clear code?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, groupbox

Been reading through the threads a lot recently as I am learning to code!

In essence all I know is self taught and very basic, so I would like to start becoming more professional

I would like to shorten this code down (in the simplest way possible) since I often end up with very repetitive code! Here is a primary example

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        textBox5.Clear();
        textBox6.Clear();
        textBox7.Clear();
        textBox8.Clear();
        textBox9.Clear();
        textBox10.Clear();
        textBox11.Clear();
        textBox12.Clear();
    }
```

For context I can't clear all textboxes on my form since `textBox13` always has a useful value that I can't have deleted!
EDIT * textBoxes 1 to 6 are in `groupBox1`, and textBoxes 7-12 are in `groupBox2`. This appears to be significant; I was just using the groupbox tool to make the program clear!

If anyone can help I would be truly grateful! Please keep in mind I am still a coding novice, so some features I am unfamiliar with.

Here is an image of the program to help!

[image]

Comment: Why not put textBox1-textBox12 into an array (but not textBox13), then you and clear them in a loop?

Comment: @Midiparse I dont want to sound like a complete idiot but still not familiar with using arrays yet! I can do basic loops though. Ive been learning for about 2 weeks as a complete beginner haha - Tom

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all your textboxes name start in the format you displayed, you could use this:

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            if (control.Name.StartsWith("textBox") && !control.Name.EndsWith("13") && control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control;
                textBox.Clear();
            }
        }
```

---

### EDIT

If you want it to work with group boxes use this code by calling ClearTextBoxes (just write "ClearTextBoxes();")

```
    private void ClearTextBoxes()
    {
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            ClearTextBox(control);
        }
    }

    private void ClearTextBox(Control control)
    {

        if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            if (control.Name.StartsWith("textBox") && !control.Name.EndsWith("13"))
            {
                TextBox textBox = (TextBox)control;
                textBox.Clear();
            }
        }
        else if (control.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
        {
            GroupBox groupBox = (GroupBox)control;

            foreach (Control groupBoxControl in groupBox.Controls)
            {
                ClearTextBox(groupBoxControl);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This works quite well; only problem is it only works on one of the groupBoxes in my program (apologies I didnt know this would cause issues)
How can I get it so it applies this to both groupBoxes rather than just clearing groupBox1 by default?

Comment: I need to go now and what you're asking is a bit complicated, don't worry I'll probably answer in the next 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The current setting doesn not allow you to clear everything quickly because each variable, even if they're all of the same type and with similar name, is a different entity and you cannot iterate through them.

Anyway, you could group them in an array and iterate through them like this:

```
// Fill this array in an Init function
YourType[] textBoxes;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Iterate through the whole array except for the last element
    for(int i=0; i<textBoxes.Length-1; i++)
    {
        textBoxes[i].Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I type the " YourType[] textBoxes; " line, it gives me the following message
"The type or namespace name "YourType" could not be found

Comment: By writing "YourType" I expected you to write the type of your textBoxes.

Comment: In this example. would it just be textBox?

Comment: Actually, can you share the code you use to create them?

Comment: Because some of my work is being assessed; I cant really share the code online in case someone got a copy of any of my code! But I do appreciate your interest and help :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be store textboxes in list

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes
```

And then iterate through this collection using **for** or **foreach** loop and calling **Clear()** method.

Or use extension method **ForEach()**

```
textBoxes.ForEach(x => x.Clear());
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to prepare a collection containing all of your textbox objects

```
var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { textBox1,textBox2,textBox3};// fill in the rest
```

and just iterate with a 'foreach' on it

```
textBoxes.ForEach(textBox => textBox.Clear());
```

This is a simple suggestion.
You can also use reflection to make it more implicit but it doesn't worth it

Comment: This works like a Charm!! Thank you to all of those who have given me support, one day I hope to give back to this community <3 - Tom

Answer (score 0):

Usually having too many of certain control can be a sign that you can consider a different type of control, but that doesn't seem to be the case based on the screenshot. You can use array:

```
foreach (var t in new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 })
    t.Clear();
```

If the controls are directly in the form then something like:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    if (c is TextBox && c.Name != "textBox13")
        c.Text = "";                            // .Text = "" is what TextBox.Clear() does
```

but because the controls are inside other controls:

```
foreach (Control c in this.groupBox1.Controls) if (c is TextBox) c.Text = ""; 
foreach (Control c in this.groupBox2.Controls) if (c is TextBox) c.Text = "";
```

or:

```
foreach (var gb in new[] { groupBox1, groupBox2 })
    foreach (Control c in gb.Controls)
        if (c is TextBox) c.Text = "";
```